# Showing that a Hermitian matrix can have eigenvalues that correspond to arbitrary numbers does not prove the Hilbert-Polya conjecture, does it?

Tags: number-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tetration, riemann-hypothesis

I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_conjecture) about the Hilbert-Polya conjecture that:

> " ...a physical reason that the Riemann hypothesis should be true, and
>   suggested that this would be the case if the imaginary parts $t$ of
>   the zeros $$\frac{1}{2} + it$$ of the Riemann zeta function
>   corresponded to eigenvalues of an unbounded self-adjoint operator."

What I have is this program that takes as input the imaginary parts of the tetrated non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function and sums them over the divisors to form a matrix that has the Greatest Common Divisor matrix (GCD(n,k)) as lookup index. As an example of this matrix I give the case $5$ times $5$:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _2)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _2)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _3)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _2)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _2)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _4)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _1)}{10 \pi }}}}}+e^{e^{e^{e^{\frac{\Im(\rho _5)}{10 \pi }}}}}
\end{array}$$

In the example matrix above the number of exponentiations is finite, but they are supposed to be infinitely many as in tetration like this:

$$\underbrace{e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{\frac{\Im (\rho_1)}{10\pi}}}}}}}_n$$

where $n \rightarrow \infty$

Division by $10\pi$ is there to avoid overflow in the program. Notice also that it is a sum over the divisors and that there are plus $+$ signs in between some of the terms.

Anyways as a Mathematica program this:

Input:

```
14.1347251417,21.0220396388,25.0108575801,30.4248761259,32.9350615877
```

---

```
(*Mathematica 8 program start*)
Clear[a, A1, A2, a2, a1, A3, nn, n, k, d, kolumn]
a[n_] := If[n < 1, 0, Sum[Im[ZetaZero[d]]/(10*Pi), {d, Divisors[n]}]]
Do[nn = j;
 A3 = Range[nn]*0;
 Do[kolumn = i;
   A1 = Table[Table[a[GCD[n, k]], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
   MatrixForm[A1];
   A1[[All, kolumn]];
   MatrixForm[
    Table[Table[
      If[Mod[n, k] == 0, MoebiusMu[n/k]*A1[[All, kolumn]][[k]], 
       0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]];
   a1 = Table[
     Total[Table[
       If[Mod[n, k] == 0, MoebiusMu[n/k]*A1[[All, kolumn]][[k]], 
        0], {k, 1, nn}]], {n, 1, nn}];
   a2 = Sign[a1]*Exp[Exp[Exp[Exp[Abs[a1]]]]];
   A2 = Table[
     Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, a2[[n/k]], 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
   MatrixForm[A2];
   a3 = Table[
     Total[Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, a2[[n/k]], 0], {k, 1, nn}]], {n, 
      1, nn}];
   A3[[i]] = a3;, {i, 1, nn}]
   MatrixForm[A3];
 Print[10*Pi*
   Reverse[N[
     Sign[Eigenvalues[A3]] Log[Log[Log[Log[Abs[Eigenvalues[A3]]]]]], 
     12]]], {j, 1, 5}]
MatrixForm[A3]
(*program end*)
```

with eigenvalues as output:

```
{14.1347251417}
{14.1347251417,21.0220396388}
{14.1347251417,21.0220396388,25.0108575801}
{14.1347251417,21.0220396388,25.0108575801,30.4248761259}
{14.1347251417,21.0220396388,25.0108575801,30.4248761259,32.9350615877}
```

Compared to the actual zeros:

```
N[Table[Im[ZetaZero[n]], {n, 1, 5}], 12]
{14.1347251417, 21.0220396388, 25.0108575801, 30.4248761259, 32.9350615877}
```

So oversimplified the program works like this:
[image: program sketch]

> My question then is:
>
> Is the matrix I presented an unbounded self-adjoint operator?

I don't know what unbounded means other than that it has to do with this inequality from wikipedia about [bounded operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator):

$$\|Lv\|_Y \le M \|v\|_X.\, \,$$

I know that the identity matrix is Hermitian and that when it is element-wise multiplied with a vector of arbitrary numbers, it will have those same numbers as eigenvalues. Although I don't know why, the identity matrix is hardly an "unbounded self-adjoint operator". What I do know is that the matrix above in this question is related to another simpler matrix that satisfies similar recurrences as the identity matrix.

---

Comment: Hmm, let $Q$ be a rotation-matrix (orthogonal) such that $Q Q^{-1} = Q Q^\tau = I$ of size $n\times n$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(\rho_0,\rho_1, \ldots \rho_{n-1})$ where the $r\rho_k$ are the imaginary parts of the k'th zeta-zero. Then the matrix $X$ defined by $X=Q \cdot D \cdot Q^{-1} = Q \cdot D \cdot Q^\tau$ is symmetric and has the zeta-zeros as eigenvalues. So this alone cannot be of too much significance, where even the rotation-matrix can be arbitrary. (Besides of that I do not exactly know whether rotation-matrices can be defined for infinite size)

Comment: @Mats : you are so boring with your "examples of matrix" !!!! why don't you describe the matrix rigorously, as everybody does ? $M$ is a $n  \times n$ matrix (you have to say what is $n$) and $M(i,j) = \ldots$ !!!

Comment: and an unbounded self-adjoint operator cannot exist in finite dimensional vector spaces, but exist in infinite dimensional vector spaces, i.e. when you let $n \to \infty$ when $n \times n$ is the size of the matrix. if all the eigenvalues of a self-adjoint operator are bounded, then the operator is bounded for the $\|.\|_2$ norm (the Hilbert space norm which comes from the usual inner product $\langle \sum_i a_i e_i , \sum_j b_j e_j \rangle = \sum_i a_i \overline{b_j}$ (where $(e_1,e_2,\ldots)$ is an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space).

Comment: (I mean't $\sum_i a_i \overline{b_i}$) this is because if the operator $U$ is self-adjoint (or normal i.e. $U U^* = U^* U$), then the spectral theorem says that $Q^*UQ$ is diagonal for some unitary operator $Q$ and $QUQ^* x = \sum_i \lambda_i e_i \langle e_i, x\rangle$ whose $\|.\|_2$ norm is $\sqrt{\sum_i |\lambda_i \langle e_i, x\rangle|^2}$ bounded by $\|x\|\max_{i}|\lambda_i| = \sqrt{ \sum_i |\langle e_i, x\rangle  \lambda_{max}|^2}$

Comment: and did you already notice that if the Fourier series coefficients of a $1$ periodic  function $h(x)$ are real (so $h(x) = \overline{h(-x)}$) then the convolution operator $H[f](x) = f \ast h(x)$ is a self-adjoint operator acting on the Hilbert space of $1$ periodic functions $f(x)$ (self-adjoint because it is diagonal and real in the Fourier series basis which is unitary) and its eigenvalues are $c_n$ the coefficients of the Fourier series for $h(x)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for the comments. Although I am not as well versed in Hilbert spaces as you are, I too by reading more in Wikipedia have now come to the conclusion that "classical" matrices cannot be unbounded self adjoint operators.